# Efficient way to sort based on multiple fields in a DB

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, sorting

Say I have the following object with these fields:

```
Student {
    age: number
    grade: x/100
    tests: number
    location: lat, long
}
```

I want to sort based on all four fields in a unified way. SQL `order by` sorts by these fields in sequential order but that's not what I mean.

I know I can sort in a "unified" way by assigning weights to each field, sum those values and sort based on that, say

`0.25 * age + 0.25 * grade + 0.25 * tests + 0.25 * distance`

but I'll have to normalize each value as it wouldn't make sense otherwise. Is there a better way to do this type of sorting?

I'm not even sure what this type of sorting/algorithm is called, that's why I'm here.

Let's also say the weights might change per teacher as some teachers value grade more than distance or something else. Distance will definitely be different per teacher. Is there a way to store one value in my DB column and sort based on that? An index so to say.

I've tried using the formula I mentioned above.

Comment: you could save the weight u another cloumn or are generated clumn that stores the weight value for all rows sererately

Comment: The weights will be different for different teachers. The distance value will definitely be different.

Comment: I think having predefined weights would be good for different priorities and having a sum column for all of them except distance - I could add distance to that column during runtime.

Comment: However, this seems rudimentary. It's literally the first thing I came up with. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163087/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77549860/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Yea, it was clear the other site was not going to be helpful.

Comment: You want to sort based on weights but without specifying what the weights are and different people might have different opinions of how to do the weighting and you want to implement these opinions but without knowing what specifically those opinions are?  This seems like a hopeless mishmash.

Comment: There is no special algorithm required here: Just compute `0.25 * age + 0.25 * grade + 0.25 * tests + 0.25 * distance` for each record, then sort by that. Postgres allows [indexes on expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html), though if the `distance` changes with every query, that would of course be problematic (but you could still do an `ORDER BY expression`; that would be a full table scan then though, it won't be able to leverage any index).

Comment: I meant that the distance would have to be computed in every query as each teacher is a different distance away from each student.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to store these weights as vectors and compute based on that. Something analogous to that.

Comment: @jjanes I already specified that I would determine what is most important to each person (i.e. age, grade, test, or distance) and then have pre defined weights based on that. Though I am looking for a cleaner solution than using weights as per the original problem statement.

Comment: @Luatic yea the indexes seem useful here tbh

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a weighted sum sorting approach, the most basic way to approach this would be to normalize each attribute to a common scale before applying the weights, for eg. scale each attribute to a range of [0,1] or use z-scores to ensure that the weight for each attribute is applied uniformly regardless of the original scale.

For the weights of the different teachers, store them in a table with the weights associating to each teacher.

With these ideologies brought in, the SQL would look something like -

```sql
-- storing teacher preferences
CREATE TABLE TeacherWeights (
    teacher_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    age_weight FLOAT,
    grade_weight FLOAT,
    tests_weight FLOAT,
    distance_weight FLOAT
);

-- get weighted sum based on teacher preferences
SELECT
    s.*,
    COALESCE(tw.age_weight, 0.25) * (age / age_max) +
    COALESCE(tw.grade_weight, 0.25) * (grade / grade_max) +
    COALESCE(tw.tests_weight, 0.25) * (tests / tests_max) +
    COALESCE(tw.distance_weight, 0.25) * (distance / distance_max) AS weighted_sum
FROM
    Student s
LEFT JOIN
    TeacherWeights tw ON s.teacher_id = tw.teacher_id
ORDER BY
    weighted_sum DESC;
```

`age_max`, `grade_max` etc. represent the maximum values for normalizations and the coalesce function handles the cases where the weight isn't specified to default a 0.25 unit value for the attributes.